# Setting onClickListener to the whole item in onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have an `RecyclerView Adapter` and I want to set the `onClick` to the whole item but this code and when I also tried it with `myViewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(..)` both still only listened to the click of the checkbox.

How can I set the `onClickListener` to the whole `item` ?

```
public class DeliveryPointSelectionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DeliveryPointSelectionAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = MyViewHolder.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<DeliveryPoint> deliveryPointList;

    interface OnItemCheckListener {
        void onItemCheck(DeliveryPoint deliveryPoint);
        void onItemUncheck(DeliveryPoint deliveryPoint);
    }

    @NonNull
    private OnItemCheckListener onItemCheckListener;

    public DeliveryPointSelectionAdapter(List<DeliveryPoint> deliveryPointList, @NonNull OnItemCheckListener onItemCheckListener) {
        this.deliveryPointList = deliveryPointList;
        this.onItemCheckListener = onItemCheckListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DeliveryPointSelectionAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_select_deliverypoints_to_change_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        DeliveryPoint deliveryPoint = deliveryPointList.get(i);
        myViewHolder.tvFormattedString.setText(deliveryPoint.domesticAddress.formattedString);
        myViewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(deliveryPoint.isCheckedForLocationUpdate);

        myViewHolder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DeliveryPoint deliveryPoint1 = deliveryPointList.get(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                if (myViewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    deliveryPoint1.setCheckedForLocationUpdate(true);
                    onItemCheckListener.onItemCheck(deliveryPoint1);
                } else {
                    deliveryPoint1.setCheckedForLocationUpdate(false);
                    onItemCheckListener.onItemUncheck(deliveryPoint1);
                }
            }
        });

//        myViewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
//            DeliveryPoint deliveryPoint1 = deliveryPointList.get(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
//            if (myViewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
//                deliveryPoint1.setCheckedForLocationUpdate(true);
//                onItemCheckListener.onItemCheck(deliveryPoint1);
//            } else {
//                deliveryPoint1.setCheckedForLocationUpdate(false);
//                onItemCheckListener.onItemUncheck(deliveryPoint1);
//            }
//        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return deliveryPointList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        return position;
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvFormattedString;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        View view;

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tvFormattedString = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_formatted_string);
            checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.cb_deliverypoint_checked);
            linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.ll_delivery_points_layout);
            this.view = view;
        }
    }
}
```

Item View Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ll_delivery_points_layout"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/cb_deliverypoint_checked"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_formatted_string"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_text_light"
            android:textSize="18sp"

            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use [`itemView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#itemView) to reference the root view of item

Comment: @art `myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener` is still only applying to checkboxes only

Comment: please, add your item view layout and update your code

Comment: @art added the item view layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like other users already mentioned `myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener` to set onClick on the recyclerView holder.
But, correct me if I am wrong, it seems you want your checkbox to be checked/unchecked only by holder click. In that case you need to disable it by adding following codes to your layout xml

```
               android:clickable="false"
               android:focusable="false"
               android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Otherwise clicking on checkbox will take its click and not execute the code you wrote for `itemview` click.

Since you are setting it to checked based on `deliveryPoint.isCheckedForLocationUpdate` you can `notifyItemChanged(position)` to update the holder checkbox after click.

See if this helps.

**EDIT:**
Based on the comments if you are actually trying to toggle your checkbox in the view you should use something like this: also if you create a new object `deliveryPoint1` no change is made to the original object you have in the view

```
myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (myViewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    deliveryPoint.setCheckedForLocationUpdate(false);
                    onItemCheckListener.onItemUncheck(deliveryPoint);
                } else {
                    deliveryPoint.setCheckedForLocationUpdate(true);
                    onItemCheckListener.onItemCheck(deliveryPoint);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I tried `myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener` and it still only set the onClickListener to the checkbox, clicking the `view` itself did nothing.

Comment: No I did not use `notify` anywhere.. When trying the `myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener` I just replaced the `linearLayout` in the question code with `itemView`.

Comment: Sorry, it seems i misread the question you are not showing any changes on holder click. But can you tell how you confirm itemview click isn't working, currently all your code does is return deliver this ```deliveryPoint1``` object via interface. no Ui changes Have you checked if your listener is set correctly.

Comment: hold on, that might actually be the issue here, will check it out.

Comment: made some edits to the answer, if you are actually trying to toggle the checkbox state on holder click

Comment: Followed what you said exactly and what I get is that it unchecks it for a millisecond and then checks it back again. But yes this kind of solution is exactly what I was after.

Comment: you should check the code in your activity where you manage what to do onItemCheck/uncheck, 
this line `        myViewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(deliveryPoint.isCheckedForLocationUpdate);` in your adapter is what sets the checkbox state,
From what you saying you might be resetting it to true or false in the code

Answer (score 2):

Firslty create a OnItemClickListener var like so:

```
public class DeliveryPointSelectionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DeliveryPointSelectionAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private OnItemClickListener listener;
```

Then towards the bottom of the class code, implement the `setOnItemClickListener` method

```
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener
                                       listener){
this.listener = listener;

}
```

Also (towards the end of your class code) you should create a new interface that will describe the data that the on click action will generate. Some thing like this:

```
public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void OnItemClick(
                int position);

}
```

Then try setting the on click listener using this method you described in your question `myViewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(..)`
But inside the `MyViewHolder(View view)` method.
Something like so:

```
      view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               int position = getAdapterPosition();
if(position !=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION&& listener
        !=null){
    listener.OnItemClick(position);
}
```

Comment: But the `MyViewHolder(View view)` method does not have the required data to change the items on click and call the `Adapter` listener?

Comment: @kataroty I have edited my answer. have a look now.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I tried to implement this but in the `MyViewHolder(View view)´ I cannot find the `listener` and overall I would like to keep the flow the current code, even though your solution might be better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to check checkbox, when it is now checked, and uncheck, when it's uncheced. Change thet conditions like by:

```
            if (myViewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
                deliveryPoint1.setCheckedForLocationUpdate(true);
                onItemCheckListener.onItemCheck(deliveryPoint1);
            } else {
                deliveryPoint1.setCheckedForLocationUpdate(false);
                onItemCheckListener.onItemUncheck(deliveryPoint1);
            }
            notifyItemChanged(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
```

And remember to call `notifyDataSetChanged();`on your adapter in your interface method.

Comment: I'm sorry but isnt it exactly the same as I have?

Comment: No, now you set false, when `checkbox.isChecked()` is false, and true, when it's true.   That has no sense, and your checkBox will never change. And add after that `notifyDataSetChanged()` in place,when you set your interface, or `notifyItemChanged()` in your adapter to tell him that data in your adapter was changed.